# Facebook Graph API, Retrieve photos uploaded by users

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I tried this:

```
SELECT pid, src, src_small, src_big, caption FROM photo WHERE aid IN (
    SELECT aid 
    FROM album 
    WHERE owner=207294952707407
)  ORDER BY created DESC
```

But with this I only manage to get Photos that are in Albums (Which I uploaded)

I would like to retrieve the photos, that other users has uploaded on my Page wall.

Whats the right fql query for that? It is possible right?

Answer (score 0):

Ok then try this GRAPH

```
207294952707407?fields=posts.fields(picture)
```

Comment: not photos where a user are tagged , i mean general if a user uploads a photo to my page's wall, this is the photo i want to retrieve

Comment: I get this: Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: 601: Parser error: unexpected '?' at position 134

Comment: http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=207294952707407?fields=posts.fields%28picture%29

Comment: @Anant is right. These photos are not in an album. You are tagged in them. See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10496869/fql-fetching-photos-of-me You may have problems getting all of them if any users have set restricted privacy.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT message,attachment,comments
FROM stream
WHERE source_id=YOUR_PAGE_ID AND filter_key="others" AND type=""
```

Is what I did to grab user's wall messages with images posted on wall, and worked like a charm :-)